# Writing the output of loop into a text file from a Ruby web crawler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, anemone

I'm a complete Ruby noob, currently going through the Treehouse tutorials but I need some quick help for outputting the content of an Anemone crawl into a text file for my job(I'm an SEO). How do I get the following to dump it's output into a text file?

```
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
 anemone.on_every_page do |page|
   puts page.url
 end
end
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `puts` to a file handle, almost the same as if it was STDOUT. A very simple adjustment to your code is to add a `File.open` block:

```
require 'anemone'

File.open('report.txt', 'w') do |file|

  Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
   anemone.on_every_page do |page|
     file.puts page.url
   end
  end

end
```